# $http error is deprecated. Use then or catch instead angular/no-http-callback

Tags: angularjs, eslint

I am trying to log the errors in the server side using custom js file(ServerLogger).In ServerLogger file I have my own method called error which will make a http call and log the error in the server side.

But I am getting an above said eslint error when I access my own error method as below.Googled but didnt get much help.Kindly help

```
angular.module('sample').config(function ($provide) {

// Adding main exception catch block for the entire application.
$provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$injector',
    function ($injector) {
        // Inject the logger for logging the exception or error in serverside.

        return (exception, cause) =>
            $injector.get('ServerLogger').error(exception, cause);
    }]);

});
```

ServerLogger

```
'use strict';

(() => {

/**
 * @ngdoc class
 * @name ServerLogger
 * @description
 * Responsible for logging the exception/errors in the server side.
 */
class ServerLogger {

    constructor($http, $log, ResourceIdService, ConfigParameters) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.$log = $log;
        this.resourceIdService = ResourceIdService;
        this.lebenServiceUrl = ConfigParameters.getLebenServiceUrl();
    }

    /**
     * @ngdoc method
     * @name logErrors
     * @methodOf apdCommon.class:ServerLogger
     * @description
     * Responsible for logging the exception/errors in the server side.
     *
     * @param {object} exception - thrown exception from the application
     * @param {object} cause - root cause of the exception
     *
     * @returns {object} promise
     */
    error(exception, cause) {
        return this.resourceIdService.gettingResourceId()
            .then(resourceId =>
            this.lebenServiceUrl
            + (resourceId ? '/' + resourceId : '') + '/log')
            .then(requestUrl => this.$http.post(requestUrl,
                getLogReqPayload(exception, cause))
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.$log.error('Logger: ' +
                        'Failed to log the angular exception details in server side'
                        + error);
                }));
    }

}

/**
 * @ngdoc method
 * @name getLogReqPayload
 * @methodOf apdCommon.class:ServerLogger
 * @description
 * Returns the formatted log message as a request payload for logging service call.
 *
 * @param {object} exception - thrown exception from the application
 * @param {object} cause - root cause of the exception
 *
 * @returns {object} returns the formatted log request payload
 */
function getLogReqPayload(exception, cause) {
    if (angular.isDefined(cause)) {
        exception.message += ' (caused by "' + cause + '")';
    }
    var message = exception.message;
    if (!message) {
        message = exception;
    }
    var logReqPayload = {
        'uiTimestamp': new Date(),
        'uiThread': 'Angular Exception:Uncaught Exception',
        'applicationVersion': 'SPA' + ':' + '1.0.0',
        'message': {
            'logMessage': angular.toJson(message),
            'stacktrace': printStackTrace({e: exception})
        }
    };
    return logReqPayload;
}

angular.module('comon').service('ServerLogger', ServerLogger);
})();
```

Comment: As it said, use `then` like `.then(function success(){}, function error(rejection){});`

Comment: I am not using $http.error method, I am trying to invoke my own error method from my own ServerLogger class.

Comment: show us your ServerLogger then

Comment: I have added the code,kindly check

Comment: so it's returning a promise since i see a `then`.  SO i stick with what i said, replace the `error` with a `then`. THe 2nd argument of the `then` is the error callback.

Comment: @walfrat: I still didnt get it. How will you invoke the .error method? And  $injector.get('ServerLogger') is not returning a promise to add a then block

Comment: Did you get a line number in the stack trace of your error message?

Comment: ah my bad, i though it was but error is a method. Try renaming your `error` method to `onError` and see if you sitll have the problem.

Comment: @walfrat : renaming the method name will solve the eslint issue, but as per my requirement the method name has to be error that is the problem.I still didnt understand why it is referring the $http's deprecated error method

Comment: @grant : yes in the decorator block,in the line  $injector.get('ServerLogger').error(exception, cause);

Comment: @user1645290 What is the result if you add `console.log($injector.get('ServerLogger');` to your decorator block? I think you may need to wait on `$injector.get` resolving and store that inside a variable to then call your `.error` method on that

Comment: i just think that eslint is too much agressive, i don't really know those tools but with jslint you could disable one special warning by adding a special comment. This is what you need i guess.

Comment: @walfrat : ya ...if nothing works need to go with that in eslint.

Comment: @grant : $injector.get returns an instance of the service, not a promise.anyhow thanks grant :)

Comment: @user1645290 When I said resolve there I wasn't specifically referring to a promise, probably a bad choice of words on my part, I was referring to the injector.get executing and returning the instance of the service -- have you managed to resolve your issue yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how, I finally accessed the error method.

```
 $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$injector',
    function ($injector) {
        return (exception, cause) => {
            $injector.invoke((ServerLogger, ServerErrorLogMessageFormatter) => {
                ServerLogger.error(
                    ServerErrorLogMessageFormatter.formatServerErrorLogMessage(
                        exception, cause));
            });
        };
    }]);
```